# How do I unlock Gunkan-Maki with two toppings?

Tags: the-sushi-spinnery

I have unlocked both the two ingredients/two toppings Nigiri and the three ingredients Makizushi in the game, but I never found out how to get an additional topping for the Gunkan-Maki. Is it available in the game, and how can you unlock it?

Answer (score 1):

There is no 2nd topping for the Gunkan-Maki.

If you take a [look at all the contest rewards](http://kairosoft.wikia.com/wiki/Contests_(The_Sushi_Spinnery))  You'll see that there are only rewards for unlocking additional ingredients to the maki and nigiri.

Comment: Maybe you can get it from reaching a high fandom level on one of the "high-end" customers, or some other crazy condition like 1000 popularity or play to year 50 or similar? It's just so obvious that this should be hidden somewhere in the game ...

Comment: @mwil.me customers only provide ingredients at higher fandoms or introduce new customers.  As for the other two, its hard to prove a negative but if you want to try for it be my guest.